# Calculate maximum inscribed rectangle in a polygon

Tags: postgis

[I saw this amazing answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368331/fitting-rectangle-with-maximum-area-inside-polygon-in-postgis), but am struggling to run the function. When I feed it a geometry it returns NULL values for each row of the input dataset.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I'm new to PostGIS so it might be a silly syntax error I don't understand....

I ran this code to get the text of the function

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
FROM pg_proc p
JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE p.proname = 'st_maximumareainscribedrectangleinpolygon'
```

And it produced this output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_maximumareainscribedrectangleinpolygon(geom geometry)
 RETURNS geometry
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
WITH
tbl_rigth AS (WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT geom1, geom2, CASE WHEN geom1>geom2 THEN geom1 WHEN geom1<=geom2 THEN geom2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
    (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS geom1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS geom2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
    tblc AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -1) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom2, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -1) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
    tbld AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom1, -1) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom1, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -1) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
    tble AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -1))).geom geom FROM tblb),
    tblf AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, ST_ExteriorRing(b.geom)) geom FROM tble a, tbla b),
    tblg AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblf a, tblf b WHERE ST_Length(a.geom)>ST_Length(b.geom)),
    tblh AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblg a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbli AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
    tblj AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tblk AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblj a JOIN tblh b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom,0.1))),
    tbll AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblk a, tblc b),
    tblm AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbll b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbln AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblm a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom,0.1))),
    tblo AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbln a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
    tblp AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a, tblc b),
    tblq AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblo a JOIN tblp b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),                             
    tblr AS (SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblh UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblk 
            UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tbln UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblq)
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblr) foo),
tbl_lefth AS (WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT geom1, geom2, CASE WHEN geom1>geom2 THEN geom1 WHEN geom1<=geom2 THEN geom2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)),
    (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS geom1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS geom2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
    tblc AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -1) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom2, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -1) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
    tbld AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom1, -1) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom1, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -1) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
    tble AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -1))).geom geom FROM tblb),
    tblf AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, ST_ExteriorRing(b.geom)) geom FROM tble a, tbla b),
    tblg AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblf a, tblf b WHERE ST_Length(a.geom)<ST_Length(b.geom)),
    tblh AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblg a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbli AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
    tblj AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tblk AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblj a JOIN tblh b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom,0.1))),
    tbll AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblk a, tblc b),
    tblm AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbll b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbln AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblm a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom,0.1))),
    tblo AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbln a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
    tblp AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a, tblc b),
    tblq AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblo a JOIN tblp b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),                             
    tblr AS (SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblh UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblk 
            UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tbln UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblq)
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblr) foo)
    SELECT geom FROM tbl_rigth UNION SELECT geom FROM tbl_lefth
    $function$
```

When I run this I get NULL values for each row of my input database

```
SELECT st_maximumareainscribedrectangleinpolygon((SELECT geometry FROM map_data LIMIT 10));
```

CRS is 7844

Version info:

```
SELECT PostGIS_Version();
3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 15.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple
clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit
```

Comment: Intuitively, the offset/buffer sizes were meant for a coordinate system using meters. Since yours is in degrees, they are likely way too big. Try with a different CRS, or with much smaller values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is actually experimental and this feature will work for trapezoidal polygons such that were presented by @Shana in her question.
You can now download this function from the following link:https://github.com/CM-FOGS/PostgreSQL-PostGIS-GeoSQL-functions-/blob/main/ST_MaximumAreaInscribedRectangleInPolygon

or

copy it from this page below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_MaximumAreaInscribedRectangleInPolygon(
   geom GEOMETRY,
   signed_distance float,
   buffer float)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
   WITH
       tbl_rigth AS (WITH 
       tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump($1)).geom),
       tblb AS (SELECT geom1, geom2, CASE WHEN geom1>geom2 THEN geom1 WHEN geom1<=geom2 THEN geom2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS geom1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS geom2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
       tblc AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom2, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
       tbld AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom1, -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom1, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
       tble AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -signed_distance))).geom geom FROM tblb),
       tblf AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, ST_ExteriorRing(b.geom)) geom FROM tble a, tbla b),
       tblg AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblf a, tblf b WHERE ST_Length(a.geom)>ST_Length(b.geom)),
       tblh AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblg a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tbli AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
       tblj AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tblk AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblj a JOIN tblh b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, buffer))),
       tbll AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblk a, tblc b),
       tblm AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbll b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tbln AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblm a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, buffer))),
       tblo AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbln a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
       tblp AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a, tblc b),
       tblq AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblo a JOIN tblp b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),    
       tblr AS (SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblh UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblk 
           UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tbln UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblq)
   SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblr) foo),
       tbl_lefth AS (WITH 
       tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump($1)).geom),
       tblb AS (SELECT geom1, geom2, CASE WHEN geom1>geom2 THEN geom1 WHEN geom1<=geom2 THEN geom2 END FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),1)), (ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2))) AS geom1, ST_MakeLine((ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),2)), 
(ST_PointN(ST_Boundary(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)),3))) AS geom2 FROM tbla) AS foo),
       tblc AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom2, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
       tbld AS (SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom1, -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb UNION SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Rotate(a.geom1, -pi(), ST_Centroid(b.geom)), -signed_distance) geom FROM tblb a, tbla b),
       tble AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_OffsetCurve(geom2, -signed_distance))).geom geom FROM tblb),
       tblf AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, ST_ExteriorRing(b.geom)) geom FROM tble a, tbla b),
       tblg AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblf a, tblf b WHERE ST_Length(a.geom)<ST_Length(b.geom)),
       tblh AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblg a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tbli AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
       tblj AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbli b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tblk AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblj a JOIN tblh b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, buffer))),
       tbll AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblk a, tblc b),
       tblm AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tbll b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
       tbln AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblm a JOIN tblk b ON ST_Disjoint(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, buffer))),
       tblo AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbln a JOIN LATERAL (SELECT (geom) AS geom FROM tbld) AS b ON true),
       tblp AS (SELECT ST_ShortestLine((ST_Dump(a.geom)).geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblh a, tblc b),
       tblq AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))).geom) geom FROM tblo a JOIN tblp b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),                  
       tblr AS (SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblh UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblk 
           UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tbln UNION SELECT (geom) geom FROM tblq)
       SELECT ST_Union(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tblr) foo)
       SELECT geom FROM tbl_rigth UNION SELECT geom FROM tbl_lefth;
   $BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run it, customizing the settings for your polygons, like this:

```
SELECT ST_MaximumAreaInscribedRectangleInPolygon(geom, 0.01, 0.001) geom FROM <polygon_name_table>
```

(-: FOGS :-)...

**Reminder!**

This function is intended for working with trapezoidal polygons, right-angled triangles, even simple n-multigons (6 or more angles), circles. In the resulting table there will be no values of records describing simple shapes like square and rectangle, if they are present in the source table!

---

This feature has another cryptic name ST_Mongoose (Herpestes)...